# error plotting series object from pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have encountered an error while working through Ch12 of the book Numerical Python: A Practical Techniques Approach for Industry (http://jrjohansson.github.io/numericalpython.html).

I am getting an error when I try to plot a series object using the pandas library.

So far the following lines of code have worked:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')
s = pd.Series([909976, 8615246, 2872086, 2273305])
s
0     909976
1    8615246
2    2872086
3    2273305
dtype: int64
```

When I plot the series object `s` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-d3eb09d34df4> in <module>()
----> 1 s.plot()

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in __call__(self, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   3495                            colormap=colormap, table=table, yerr=yerr,
   3496                            xerr=xerr, label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 3497                            **kwds)
   3498     __call__.__doc__ = plot_series.__doc__
   3499 

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in plot_series(data, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   2585                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   2586                  label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2587                  **kwds)
   2588 
   2589 

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   2382         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   2383 
-> 2384     plot_obj.generate()
   2385     plot_obj.draw()
   2386     return plot_obj.result

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in generate(self)
    985         self._compute_plot_data()
    986         self._setup_subplots()
--> 987         self._make_plot()
    988         self._add_table()
    989         self._make_legend()

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _make_plot(self)
   1662                              stacking_id=stacking_id,
   1663                              is_errorbar=is_errorbar,
-> 1664                              **kwds)
   1665             self._add_legend_handle(newlines[0], label, index=i)
   1666 

anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _plot(cls, ax, x, y, style, column_num, stacking_id, **kwds)
   1676             cls._initialize_stacker(ax, stacking_id, len(y))
   1677         y_values = cls._get_stacked_values(ax, stacking_id, y, kwds['label'])
-> 1678         lines = MPLPlot._plot(ax, x, y_values, style=style, **kwds)
   1679         cls._update_stacker(ax, stacking_id, y)
   1680         return lines

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _plot(cls, ax, x, y, style, is_errorbar, **kwds)
   1298             else:
   1299                 args = (x, y)
-> 1300             return ax.plot(*args, **kwds)
   1301 
   1302     def _get_index_name(self):

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1809                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1810                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1811             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1812         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1813         if pre_doc is None:

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1425             kwargs['color'] = c
   1426 
-> 1427         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   1428             self.add_line(line)
   1429             lines.append(line)

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    384                 return
    385             if len(remaining) <= 3:
--> 386                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
    387                     yield seg
    388                 return

anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    372         ncx, ncy = x.shape[1], y.shape[1]
    373         for j in xrange(max(ncx, ncy)):
--> 374             seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
    375             ret.append(seg)
    376         return ret

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _makeline(self, x, y, kw, kwargs)
    278         default_dict = self._getdefaults(None, kw, kwargs)
    279         self._setdefaults(default_dict, kw, kwargs)
--> 280         seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
    281         self.set_lineprops(seg, **kwargs)
    282         return seg

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py in __init__(self, xdata, ydata, linewidth, linestyle, color, marker, markersize, markeredgewidth, markeredgecolor, markerfacecolor, markerfacecoloralt, fillstyle, antialiased, dash_capstyle, solid_capstyle, dash_joinstyle, solid_joinstyle, pickradius, drawstyle, markevery, **kwargs)
    364         # update kwargs before updating data to give the caller a
    365         # chance to init axes (and hence unit support)
--> 366         self.update(kwargs)
    367         self.pickradius = pickradius
    368         self.ind_offset = 0

/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in update(self, props)
    854                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
    855                 if func is None or not six.callable(func):
--> 856                     raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
    857                 func(v)
    858             changed = True

AttributeError: Unknown property color_cycle
```

I have a 64 bit linux OS and the most recent anaconda installed.

Comment: Remove the line `pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')` and you should be good. There's an issue somewhere on pandas' github about this.

Comment: for me it works well plotting the series with `s.plot()`, but I'm on Python 2.7.11.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it to work after removing     pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')